# how to include custom title view with in AlertDialog in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, custom-titlebar

how can i include custom titlebar in alertDialog?I know android sdk provide setCustomTitle method but it does'not work

edit:

```
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Test").setMessage("hello").show();
    View view=alert.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
    alert.setCustomTitle(view);
```

but above code is not working

**NOTE :** 
I am not looking for custom dialog box but only want to makes its title layout custom..Like below[image: like this with close Button]

Comment: This will show,how you create a custom dialog http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: I know how to create custom dialogbox but I dont want any custom dialogbox but only need custum title,so that i can add button to its title, anyway thanks

Comment: not working means? is it giving some error? or simply not showing the custom title? i think the code is correct it should work.

Comment: @Vikram its showing default title bar.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

you should not use the .show method with the first line, use the following code it works:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
alert.setCustomTitle(view);
alert.setMessage("helo");
alert.show();
```

Comment: getLayoutInflater() crashes my fragment in onCreateDialog. LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()) works.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DisplayDialog d = new DisplayDialog(this);
    d.show();

    public class DisplayDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
    {
        public DisplayDialog(Context c) 
        {
            super(c, R.style.Theme_Dialog_Translucent);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        }
    }
```

Add this snippet to your `strings.xml`

```
 <style name="Theme_Dialog_Translucent" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
     <item name = "android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
 </style>
 <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Use `dismiss();` to close the dialog